# Laravel Query Builder Join vs With Function, Which One is Better?

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

I want to ask about Laravel Query using **Join** or **With** which is better.

In this case there is a short query that I have tried. But there are some things that make me wonder.

In my case, I'm trying to create a list of users using the API. The problem lies in **sorting** the data.

The problem is divided into several.

1. If I use **With**.
   The advantage of using with is that I can call the attributes in the model without rewriting the attributes I want to use. But I was confused when calling data related to other tables for me to **sort**. example query:

```php
     /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $sortBy = $request->query('sortBy');
        $sortDesc = (is_null($request->query('sortDesc'))) ? $request->query('sortDesc') : ($request->query('sortDesc') == 'true' ? 'desc' : 'asc');
        $page = $request->query('page');
        $itemsPerPage = $request->query('itemsPerPage');
        $search = $request->query('search');
        $starDate = $request->query('start');
        $endDate = $request->query('end');

        $start = ($page - 1) * $itemsPerPage;

        $query = MemberRegular::query();
        $query->with(['users' => function ($subQuery) {
            $subQuery->select('id', 'name', 'email', 'phone');
        }]);
        $query->select(
            'id',
            'code'
        );

        if ($search) {
            $query->where(function ($subQuery) use ($search) {
                $subQuery->where('code', 'like', '%' . $search . '%');
                $subQuery->orWhere(function ($q) use ($search) {
                    $q->whereHas('users', function ($j) use ($search) {
                        $j->where('name', 'like', '%' . $search . '%');
                        $j->orWhere('email', 'like', '%' . $search . '%');
                    })
                });
            });
        }

        if ($sortBy && $sortDesc) {
            $query->orderBy($sortBy, $sortDesc)->orderBy('id', 'desc');
        } else {
            $query->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->orderBy('id', 'desc');
        }

        if ($starDate && $endDate) {
            $query->whereBetween('created_at', [$starDate, $endDate]);
        }
        $data['totalItems'] = $query->count();
        $data['items'] = $query->skip($start)->take($itemsPerPage)->get();
        return HResource::collection($data['items'])->additional(['totalItems' => (int) $data['totalItems']], true);
    }
```

2. If I use **Join**.
   The advantage of using **Join** is that I can **sort** data easily if the data is related to other tables. But I have to re-create a new attribute in a **collection**. example query:

```php
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $sortBy = $request->query('sortBy');
        $sortDesc = (is_null($request->query('sortDesc'))) ? $request->query('sortDesc') : ($request->query('sortDesc') == 'true' ? 'desc' : 'asc');
        $page = $request->query('page');
        $itemsPerPage = $request->query('itemsPerPage');
        $search = $request->query('search');
        $starDate = $request->query('start');
        $endDate = $request->query('end');

        $start = ($page - 1) * $itemsPerPage;

        $query = MemberRegular::query();
        $query->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'member_regulars.user_id');
        $query->select(
            'member_regulars.id',
            'member_regulars.code',
            'users.name',
            'users.email',
            'users.phone'
        );

        if ($search) {
            $query->where(function ($subQuery) use ($search) {
                $subQuery->where('member_regulars.code', 'like', '%' . $search . '%');
                $subQuery->orWhere('users.name', 'ilike', '%' . $search . '%');
                $subQuery->orWhere('users.email', 'ilike', '%' . $search . '%');
                $subQuery->orWhere('users.phone', 'ilike', '%' . $search . '%');
            });
        }

        if ($sortBy && $sortDesc) {
            $query->orderBy($sortBy, $sortDesc)->orderBy('member_regulars.id', 'desc');
        } else {
            $query->orderBy('member_regulars.created_at', 'desc')->orderBy('member_regulars.id', 'desc');
        }

        if ($starDate && $endDate) {
            $query->whereBetween('member_regulars.created_at', [$starDate, $endDate]);
        }
        $data['totalItems'] = $query->count();
        $data['items'] = $query->skip($start)->take($itemsPerPage)->get();
        return HResource::collection($data['items'])->additional(['totalItems' => (int) $data['totalItems']], true);
    }
```

1. If using Query **With** The problem lies in sending the **sortBy** parameter like the following **users.name** it will be an error because the table is not found in the query I made, but I can immediately call attributes that can be used directly without needing to create a new custom attribute.
2. If using Query **Join**, the problem is that I have to re-create custom attributes to be used in data collections, but I don't need to worry about **sorting** data.

Both are equally important to me. However, if anyone is willing to give advice on the best way I have to use **Join** or **With** for this case.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the best solution to the problem I was facing. I hope this can help others.

Here I choose to use **Join** why? because it turns out that I can call the function relations **users()** in the model that I created so that I can still retrieve custom attributes in the **Users** model. I don't really know if this is the right way or not. I hope this helps others.

Thank you.